# Does play store filter out NFC apps for phones which do not have NFC?

Tags: google-play-store, nfc

I'm developing an Android app based on NFC technology.

So when my app goes live on the play store, will the app be displayed for people having non-NFC phones? Will they be shown a message like "this app is not supported on your phone" or will they have to face post-installation frustration?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That depends on the app. For using NFC in an app the developer has to declare that in the app's `AndroidManifest.xml` that is contained it the app (and used by the PlayStore to detect if an app is compatible at all).

When using a feature you can declare if it is `required=true` or not, if it is not required it is considered optional:

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.nfc" android:required="true"/>
```

Therefore for apps that declare the NFC feature as `required=true` PlayStore will not show you those apps on a non NFC phone. If it is set to optional (`required=false`) then you will be able to see this app.

See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52695866/does-nfc-permission-result-in-an-error-when-the-device-has-no-support